# Error de compilación en app Vue (Parsing error)

Tags: vue.js, plugin, webpack

Estoy empezando a usar Vue y conociendo la gama de plugins que es posible incorporar con webpack para usarlos en el mismo. La cuestión es que al instalar EsLint, me sale el siguiente error en la compilación:

```
Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing 
tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

   6 | </template>
   7 | 
>  8 | <script>
     | ^
   9 | export default {
  10 |   name: "app",
  11 |
```

Buscando encontré que solo necesitaba instalar Babel-eslint y un plugin para que eslint funcione bien con HTML. De todas formas, esto no lo resolvió.
Debajo dejo los archivos que creo que les servirán.

**App Vue.js**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <img src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "app",

    data() {
        return {
           msg: "Hola Vue!"
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "extends": "standard",
  "rules": {
    "no-new": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0
  },
  "plugins": [
    "html"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

**Packaje.json (Solo dependencias)**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^13.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
```